# What is a 'fortune d'amour'?

Tags: noms, de

The phrase is used in Maupassant's story 'La Chevelure' and refers to a lock of female hair found by the narrator in an antique piece of funiture. He speculates about its history:

> Est-ce à l'heure d'entrer au cloître qu'on avait jeté là **cette fortune d'amour**, comme un gage laissé au monde des vivants ?

I don't see the phrase listed in any dictionary and can't guess its meaning.

Answer (score 1):

There is an allegory called *[Fortune d'amour](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Iconologie_(Cesare_Ripa,_1643)/II/Fortune_d%E2%80%99Amour)*.

[image]

I'm not sure there is direct relationship with it but maybe Maupassant meant that the future nun showed by this symbol that she renounced all but spiritual love.

To the protagonist, these hairs were also a *fortune* (with it's "chance" meaning, an unexpected lucky finding) that he fell in love with.